# Cannot load azure.ml workspace from within a webservice entry_script! Where is the `/var/azureml-app/` located?

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, entry-point

I am creating an azure-ml webservice. The following script shows the code for creating the webservice and deploying it locally.

```
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig
from azureml.core.environment import Environment
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.model import Model

ws = Workspace.from_config()
model = Model(ws,'textDNN-20News')

ws.write_config(file_name='config.json')

env = Environment(name="init-env")
python_packages = ['numpy', 'pandas']

for package in python_packages:
    env.python.conda_dependencies.add_pip_package(package)

dummy_inference_config = InferenceConfig(
    environment=env,
    source_directory="./source_dir",
    entry_script="./init_score.py",
)

from azureml.core.webservice import LocalWebservice
deployment_config = LocalWebservice.deploy_configuration(port=6789)

service = Model.deploy(
    ws,
    "myservice",
    [model],
    dummy_inference_config,
    deployment_config,
    overwrite=True,
)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

As it can be seen, the above code deploys "entry_script = init_score.py" to my local machine. Within the entry_script, I need to load the workspace again to connect to azure SQL database. I do it like the following :

```
from azureml.core import Dataset, Datastore
from azureml.data.datapath import DataPath
from azureml.core import Workspace

def init():
    pass

def run(data):
  try:
    ws = Workspace.from_config()

    # create tabular dataset from a SQL database in datastore
    datastore = Datastore.get(ws, 'sql_db_name')
    query = DataPath(datastore, 'SELECT * FROM my_table')
    tabular = Dataset.Tabular.from_sql_query(query, query_timeout=10)
    df = tabular.to_pandas_dataframe()

    return len(df)

  except Exception as e:
    output0 = "{}:".format(type(e).__name__)
    output1 = "{} ".format(e)
    output2 = f"{type(e).__name__} occured at line {e.__traceback__.tb_lineno} of {__file__}"
    return output0 + output1 + output2
```

The `try-catch` block is for catching the potential exception thrown and return it as an output.

The exception that I keep getting is:

```
UserErrorException: The workspace configuration file config.json, could not be found in /var/azureml-app or its 
parent directories. Please check whether the workspace configuration file exists, or provide the full path 
to the configuration file as an argument. You can download a configuration file for your workspace, 
via http://ml.azure.com and clicking on the name of your workspace in the right top.
```

I have actually tried to save the config file by passing an absolute path to the `path` argument of both `ws.write_config(path='my_absolute_path')`, and also when loading it to the `Workspace.from_config(path='my_absolute_path')`, but I got pretty much the same error:

```
UserErrorException: The workspace configuration file config.json, could not be found in /var/azureml-app/my_absolute_path or its 
parent directories. Please check whether the workspace configuration file exists, or provide the full path 
to the configuration file as an argument. You can download a configuration file for your workspace, 
via http://ml.azure.com and clicking on the name of your workspace in the right top.
```

Looks like even providing the `path` does not change the root directory that the entry script starts locating from.

I also tried to directly saving the file to `/var/azureml-app/`, but this path is not recognized when I passed it to the `ws.write_config(path='/var/azureml-app/')`.

Do you have any idea where exactly is the `/var/azureml-app/`?
Any idea on how to fix this?